# Error: Could not find or load main class. Running maven jar-with-dependencies

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

I am using Maven to manage a personal project and am getting this maven error whenever I try to run my jar with dependencies.

```
$ java -jar .\SpotifyAutomation-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar
Error: Could not find or load main class SpotifyRunner
```

(I do a clean and install before running).

My pom file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>SpotifyAutomation</groupId>
<artifactId>SpotifyAutomation</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <classpathPrefix>lib</classpathPrefix>
                        <mainClass>SpotifyRunner</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>se.michaelthelin.spotify</groupId>
        <artifactId>spotify-web-api-java</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Any insight on how I might go about fixing this? I have tried switching around my classpathPrefix but to no avail. My project has one module and one package.

My project structure is shown in the below image:
[Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h0QYI.png)

Comment: Does specifying the main class not require complete package name?

Comment: I don't have a specified package since there's just one in the project so I thought I didn't have to. Given my project structure (added above), what would that look like?

Comment: Look inside the jar file and see what the filename of your classfile is.  Then reconstruct the package name needed.

Comment: Upon looking at the contents of the jar, I see a ton of classfiles. I just did a jar tf. Is there a better way to look for that? Thanks.